# Why parseInt return 1 for 31 bit binary

Tags: javascript, c#

In C# if I do

```
var value = Convert.ToInt32("1000000000000000000000000000000", 2);
```

It will return `1073741824` but when I do the same in javascript,

```
parseInt(1000000000000000000000000000000,2)
```

It return `1` but not `1073741824`

Comment: In JavaScript you are not passing a string...

Comment: Put it in a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `string` as first parameter

```js
console.log(parseInt("1000000000000000000000000000000",2))
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because in JavaScript you're lacking the quotation marks :)

```
parseInt("1000000000000000000000000000000",2)
```

works fine.